# Como se recuperan las variables de entorno en NodeJS?

Tags: nodejs

Supongamos que tengo definida una variable de entorno en mi shell de unix con una clave, por ejemplo:

```
export DEV_KEY=abcd123abcd123abcd123
```

De que manera podría acceder a esa variable dentro del código de un programa de NodeJS? El objetivo es que la clave no forme parte del código del programa node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mediante [`process.env`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env). Esta propiedad retorna un objeto con todas las variables de entorno del usuario o de sesión local:

```
let key = process.env.DEV_KEY;
```

Comment: corto y preciso

Answer (score 1):

Como complemento a la respuesta decir también que puedes usar la notación array `process.env['FOO']`