# Como utilizar las variables de entorno en nodejs con el archivo .env

Tags: nodejs

El problema que tengo es un error al tratar de usar la variable:

```
process.env.BOT_TOKEN
```

Me sale un error que dice lo siguiente:

```
Error: 401: Bot Token is required
```

Entiendo que puedo usar un archivo con la extesión `.env` para almacenar estas variables pero no se como recuperarlas. La otra opción es usar directamente el valor de las variables, pero no deseo mostrar explícitamente el valor de mis variables en mi código, ya que lo subiré a un repositorio público.

En esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54089/como-se-recuperan-las-variables-de-entorno-en-nodejs) se muestra como recuperar las variables de entorno, una vez han sido creadas en el sistema, pero en mi caso quiero usar las variables desde el archivo `.env` no directamente desde las variables del sistema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa [dotoenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) para soportar los archivos .env.

Los archivos .env no se trackean en GIT, es decir, configuras tu archivo .gitignore para que no lo tome en cuenta.

La doc de dotenv es muy clara, pero básicamente tienes que importarlo al inicio de tu código y con eso ;D

La manera de acceder a las variables es como colocas en tu pregunta.

Digamos que en el .env tienes:

DB_HOST='mihost'

En código accedes: process.env.DB_HOST.

Extra:

Es recomendable que agregues un .env.example con las variables de entorno que necesitas (pero sin valor, claro).